# mac excel vba loop : from list & then export as pdf

Tags: vba, excel, pdf

So lost myself in this: I have a list on one sheet (studentlist) that has 160 student numbers. Would like to paste each student number in cell A1 ion the Feedback sheet and then export as pdf to a file with the student number as the filename.
Got this far...
Cheers
Mike

```
Sub Pdfexportmacro()

Dim rCell As Range
Dim rRng As Range
Dim SNum As Integer

'Student numbers in cells A7:A160, set to A7:A9 for testing
Sheets("studentlist").Activate
Set rRng = Range("A7:A9")

For Each rCell In rRng.Cells
     SNum = rCell.Value

     ' Write student number to cell A1 on Feedback sheet:
        Sheets("Feedback").Activate
        Range(“A1”).Activate
        ActiveCell.Value = SNum

       ' Export & save file as pdf using SNum as filename:
        ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
        "Macintosh HD:Users:Michael:Desktop:" & rCell.Value, Quality:= _
        xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
        OpenAfterPublish:=False

Next rCell

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not a MAC user so I may be missing some restrictions I don't have in Windows OS, but you may be after something like follows:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Pdfexportmacro()

    Dim rCell As Range, rRng As Range

    'Student numbers in cells A7:A160
    Set rRng = Worksheets("studentlist").Range("A7:A160") '<--| set your "students" range

    With Worksheets("Feedback") '<--| reference "Feedback" worksheet
        For Each rCell In rRng '<--| loop through "students" range
            .Range("A1").Value = rCell.Value '<--| write current student number to cell A1 on Feedback sheet

           ' Export & save file as pdf using SNum as filename:
            .ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, fileName:= _
            "Macintosh HD:Users:Michael:Desktop:" & rCell.Value, Quality:= _
            xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
            OpenAfterPublish:=False
        Next rCell
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Ok, so the loop works and puts the numbers in to cell A1, but the export to pdf does not - looks as if it is looping through all the pages possible and not saving..

Comment: I tested it and it works: I get as many pdfs as cells looped in `Worksheets("studentlist").Range("A7:A160")` and each of them has the proper "student" value in its cell A1

Comment: @SolarMike, did you get through it?

Comment: Hi, tried it again, loop works, but I think the network printer for work causes a problem - will see if i can get round that ideas are avoid the printer or try to use save as...

Comment: Hi, so the loop works, but the printer gets called... and that has a login and password which stops it...Also the macro, even though set to use the print area (1 page) prints everything on each sheet with data - 128 pages...

Comment: Well, my code does what you asked for ("Would like to paste each student number in cell A1 ion the Feedback sheet and then export as pdf to a file with the student number as the filename") while your question didn't mention any printer or print area issues. You may want to accept this answer and post a new question with the new issues along all its relevant details