# Excel-vba to save different sheets to PDF in different folders

Tags: excel, vba, pdf

I have been working om my "rental plan" and its quite good. 
But i would like to make things even better.

Unfortunatly i don't have the skills to write VBA codes myself, so i hope you can help me.

In my workbook i have 4 different sheets "info" "offer" "lease" and "invoice"

When i have typed in the info in "info" i would like to click a button and then it saves "offer" "lease" and "invoice" into 3 specific different folders as .pdf,
with a name generated from 2 differents cells in the "info" sheet.

I have been searching for a solution but havent found it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: This isn't a code writing service, so either you need to brush up on your VBA or brush up on your research skills.

Comment: You could do a search on here and start to edit the code to your needs, here is just one example : https://stackoverflow.com/q/40690592/4961700

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out, and perhapse it could be useful for others.

Saves 3 sheets to different locations, with the name from cells in one specific sheet.

```
Sub SaveAsPDF()


Dim fName As String
With Worksheets("Pricelist")
    fName = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Pricelist").Range("D1").Value & 
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Pricelist").Range("E10").Value & 
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Pricelist").Range("D4").Value
End With
Worksheets("Offer").ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
        "C:\Users\ra\2019\Offer\" & fName, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
        IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False

Worksheets("Invoice").ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
        "C:\Users\ra\2019\Invoice\" & fName, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
        IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False

Worksheets("Rental").ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
        "C:\Users\ra\2019\Rental\" & fName, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
        IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False
End Sub
```