# Is there a way to bulk create word docs

Tags: excel, ms-word

I am trying to bulk create individual Word documents from a list in excel.

Example list:

```
  **Excel Column A**(Document Titles)
  **Row 1:** MAIN 08-30-18 - ECOM
  **Row 2:** SF 08-31-18 - DRM
  **Row 3:** MAIN 09-01-18 - SPONSORED
```

I am trying to skip the manual step of creating and saving hundreds of new files individually.

Does anyone have a creative solution?

Comment: Se this Q&A - that code works through a list creating files in excel, edit it as you need, if ithelpsgive it a vote : https://stackoverflow.com/q/40690592/4961700

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your filenames starts with cell A1, A2, A3..... and below code will create the word files with sample text

```
Sub TEST1()
    Dim lastrow As Variant
    Dim wrdApp As Word.Application
    Dim wrdDoc As Word.Document
    Dim i, j As Integer
    lastrow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For j = 1 To lastrow
        Set wrdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
        wrdApp.Visible = True
        Set wrdDoc = wrdApp.Documents.Add
        With wrdDoc
            For i = 1 To 5
                .Content.InsertAfter "Sample Test Line #" & i
                .Content.InsertParagraphAfter
            Next i
            'change the below location
            If Dir("C:\work\MyNewWordDoc" & j & ".doc") <> "" Then ' Check if file exists already
                Kill "C:\work\MyNewWordDoc.doc"
            End If
            .SaveAs ("C:\work\MyNewWordDoc" & j & ".doc")
            .Close ' close the document
        End With
        wrdApp.Quit ' close the Word application
        Set wrdDoc = Nothing
        Set wrdApp = Nothing
    Next j
End Sub
```