# Saving a xlsm file with the name of specific cell through vba macro

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to make a button that saves my workbook with the name of a specific cell from one of its own sheets.

The cell that I'm getting the name from is gonna change it's value each week.
I get the error:

```
Run-time error '1004':
Method 'SaveAs' of object'_Workbook' failed
```

Here is the code:

```
Private Sub Save_file_Click()
Dim path As String
Dim filename1 As String
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Fejlregistrering")

path = "C:\Users\JOHLA\Desktop\Yield ark\"
filename1 = ws.Range("D5").Text
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs path & filename1 & ".xlsm", FileFormat =  xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled


End Sub
```

//Johan

Comment: Please insert your error as text, not as picture.

Comment: If you add `Debug.Print filename1` before the `SaveAs` line, then is it outputting the correct value?  (Also, as the first 2 arguments in order, there is no need to name them)

Comment: Have a look at how I build the filename in this code... https://stackoverflow.com/q/40690592/4961700  taking a number directly from the sheet that is to be saved.

Comment: The debug.print filename1 helped! Unfortunately my cell had one of the forbidden signs :-(

Answer (score 1):

Change

`ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs path & filename1 & ".xlsm", FileFormat =  xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled`

to

`ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=(path & filename1 & ".xlsm"), FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled`

Comment: Now i'm just getting this error:  
Run-time error '1004':  
The file could not be  accessed. Try one of the following.  
1. Make sure  the specified folder excists.  
2. Make sure the folder that contains the file is not a read-only.  
3. Make sure the file/path doesn't contain more than 218 signs.  
4. Make sure the filename doesn't contain any of the following characters:  
< > ? [ ] : | or *

Comment: You checked all these? Wild guess, your field where the filename is from contains one of the following: < > ? [ ] : | or *

Comment: The current file is saved the same place as the new file :-/

Comment: What do you mean? Add { Debug.Print (path & filename1 & ".xlsm") }  (without the brackets) before your SaveAs statement and post the result here.

Answer (score 0):

try with below

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=path & filename1, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled
```

Comment: I'm getting the same error as when i tried the version @Lucky mensioned.

Comment: @JohanLarsen, instead of Activeworkbook, please add workbooks("workbookname.xls").Sheets("Fejlregistrering")

Comment: Since my workbook will change name every week activeworkbook does it's job.