# Cannot kill excel applications in background

Tags: excel, vb.net, background-process

I'm new in programming. this is the first system application that I did. I'm struggling in closing or killing the excel application once the system has successfully uploaded in a repository. this is my code. I do hope you can help me to fix it. thank you in advance.

Private Sub bgw_DoWork(sender As Object, e As DoWorkEventArgs) Handles bgw.DoWork

```
    srcXlApp = New Excel.Application
    dstXlApp = New Excel.Application

    Dim numToDo As Integer = CInt(e.Argument)
    Dim ComputerName As String
    Dim strMissingValues As String


    Try

        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(srcXlWb)
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(dstXlWb)

        isValidUploading = True
        strMissingValues = "Cannot upload there are missing fields: "

        bgwState = e

        strRemarks = txtRemarks.Text

        srcXlApp.DisplayAlerts = False
        srcXlWbs = srcXlApp.Workbooks
        srcXlWb = srcXlWbs.Open(srcFilePath)
        srcXlWrksht = srcXlWb.Worksheets(1)
        srcXlApp.Visible = False



        'Step 1 - open source
        bgw.ReportProgress(Convert.ToInt32((1 / numToDo) * 100))
        'System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000)
        ComputerName = System.Net.Dns.GetHostName
        'dstFilePath = "C:\Users\" & ComputerName & "\Desktop\Mazza\trunk\QA Task Monitoring_2020.xlsx"

        If ComputerName = "jonas" Then
            'MessageBox.Show(ComputerName)
            dstFilePath = "C:\Users\jonas.ONE-SOURCE\Desktop\Mazza\trunk\QA Task Monitoring_for_testing_only.xlsx"
        Else
            dstFilePath = "C:\Users\" & ComputerName & "\Desktop\Mazza\trunk\QA Task Monitoring_for_testing_only.xlsx"
        End If

        'dstFilePath = "C:\Users\jonas.ONE-SOURCE\Desktop\Mazza\trunk\QA Task Monitoring_2020.xlsx"
        'dstFilePath = "C:\Users\" & ComputerName & "\Desktop\Mazza\trunk\QA Task Monitoring_for_testing_only.xlsx"

        dstXlApp.DisplayAlerts = False
        dstXlWbs = dstXlApp.Workbooks
        dstXlWb = dstXlWbs.Open(dstFilePath)
        dstXlApp.Visible = False

        'Step 2 - open destination
        bgw.ReportProgress(Convert.ToInt32((2 / numToDo) * 100))
        'System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000)


        'Step 3 - Copy Range
        bgw.ReportProgress(Convert.ToInt32((3 / numToDo) * 100))
        'System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000)

        'Code for copying cells

        srcXlWrksht = srcXlWb.Worksheets(1)

        strTicketNumber = srcXlWrksht.Range("B3").Value
        strCID = srcXlWrksht.Range("B4").Value
        strIteration = srcXlWrksht.Range("B13").Value
        If Not IsNothing(strIteration) Then
            strIteration = strIteration.Substring(2)
        End If

        strSystem = srcXlWrksht.Range("B17").Value
        strAssignedBy = srcXlWrksht.Range("B10").Value
        strPMOBA = srcXlWrksht.Range("B9").Value
        strRequest = srcXlWrksht.Range("B5").Value
        strAssign = srcXlWrksht.Range("B6").Value
        strStart = srcXlWrksht.Range("B14").Value
        strEnd = srcXlWrksht.Range("B15").Value
        strStatus = srcXlWrksht.Range("C24").Value
        strTask = srcXlWrksht.Range("B16").Value


        If srcXlWb.Worksheets.Count >= 2 Then
            srcXlWrksht = srcXlWb.Worksheets(2)
            strDescription = srcXlWrksht.Range("D3").Value
        Else
            'strMissingValues = strMissingValues & vbCrLf & "Title/Description"
            isValidUploading = False
        End If


        'srcXlWrksht = srcXlWb.Worksheets(2)
        'strDescription = srcXlWrksht.Range("D3").Value


        If strTicketNumber = "" Then
            strMissingValues = strMissingValues & vbCrLf & "Ticket ID"
            isValidUploading = False
        End If


        If strCID = "" Then
            strMissingValues = strMissingValues & vbCrLf & "Change ID"
            isValidUploading = False
        End If


        If strIteration = "" Then
            strMissingValues = strMissingValues & vbCrLf & "Iteration Number"
            isValidUploading = False
        End If


        If strSystem = "" Then
            strMissingValues = strMissingValues & vbCrLf & "System Name"
            isValidUploading = False
        End If


        If strAssignedBy = "" Then
            strMissingValues = strMissingValues & vbCrLf & "Assigned By"
            isValidUploading = False
        End If


        If strPMOBA = "" Then
            strMissingValues = strMissingValues & vbCrLf & "Assigned PMO/BA"
            isValidUploading = False
        End If


        If strRequest = "" Then
            strMissingValues = strMissingValues & vbCrLf & "Requested Date"
            isValidUploading = False
        End If


        If strAssign = "" Then
            strMissingValues = strMissingValues & vbCrLf & "Assigned Date"
            isValidUploading = False
        End If

        If strStart = "" Then
            strMissingValues = strMissingValues & vbCrLf & "Start Date"
            isValidUploading = False
        End If

        If strEnd = "" Then
            strMissingValues = strMissingValues & vbCrLf & "End Date"
            isValidUploading = False
        End If


        If strStatus = "" Then
            strMissingValues = strMissingValues & vbCrLf & "Status"
            isValidUploading = False
        End If


        If strTask = "" Then
            strMissingValues = strMissingValues & vbCrLf & "Task type"
            isValidUploading = False
        End If


        If strDescription = "" Then
            strMissingValues = strMissingValues & vbCrLf & "Title/Description"
            isValidUploading = False
        End If

        'If CheckBox1.CheckState = CheckState.Checked And txtRemarks.Text = "" Then
        '    strMissingValues = strMissingValues & vbCrLf & "Empty Remarks"
        '    MessageBox.Show("Please input remarks", "Empty Remarks", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
        '    isValidUploading = False
        'End If
        If Not isValidUploading Then
            MessageBox.Show(strMissingValues, "ERROR", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)

            srcXlWb.Close()
            dstXlWb.Close()
            srcXlApp.UserControl = True
            dstXlApp.UserControl = True
            srcXlApp.Quit()
            dstXlApp.Quit()


            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(dstXlWrksht)
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(dstXlWb)
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(dstXlWbs)
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(dstXlApp)
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(dstXlWrksht)
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(srcXlWb)
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(srcXlWbs)
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(srcXlApp)

            GC.Collect()
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers()
            GC.Collect()
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers()
            GC.Collect()
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers()

            bgw.CancelAsync()
            e.Cancel = True
            Exit Sub
        End If

        'strTicketNumber = srcXlWrksht.Range("B4").Value.ToString


        'code for pastespecial
        dstXlWb.Worksheets("Tasks").Range("A3").Select()
        Last_Row = dstXlWb.Worksheets("Tasks").Range("A3").End(Excel.XlDirection.xlDown).Row + 1
        dstXlWb.Worksheets("Tasks").Range("A" & Last_Row).Select()

        'Step 4 - Pasting values
        bgw.ReportProgress(Convert.ToInt32((4 / numToDo) * 100))

        'System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000)

        dstXlWb.Worksheets("Tasks").Range("C" & Last_Row).Value = strTicketNumber
        dstXlWb.Worksheets("Tasks").Range("B" & Last_Row).Value = strQAT
        dstXlWb.Worksheets("Tasks").Range("D" & Last_Row).Value = strCID
        dstXlWb.Worksheets("Tasks").Range("E" & Last_Row).Value = strIteration
        dstXlWb.Worksheets("Tasks").Range("F" & Last_Row).Value = strDescription
        dstXlWb.Worksheets("Tasks").Range("G" & Last_Row).Value = strSystem
        dstXlWb.Worksheets("Tasks").Range("H" & Last_Row).Value = strAssignedBy
        dstXlWb.Worksheets("Tasks").Range("I" & Last_Row).Value = strPMOBA
        dstXlWb.Worksheets("Tasks").Range("J" & Last_Row).Value = strSBU
        dstXlWb.Worksheets("Tasks").Range("K" & Last_Row).Value = strTypes
        dstXlWb.Worksheets("Tasks").Range("L" & Last_Row).Value = strProcess
        dstXlWb.Worksheets("Tasks").Range("M" & Last_Row).Value = strRequest
        dstXlWb.Worksheets("Tasks").Range("N" & Last_Row).Value = strAssign
        dstXlWb.Worksheets("Tasks").Range("O" & Last_Row).Value = strStart
        dstXlWb.Worksheets("Tasks").Range("P" & Last_Row).Value = strEnd
        dstXlWb.Worksheets("Tasks").Range("Q" & Last_Row).Value = strStatus
        dstXlWb.Worksheets("Tasks").Range("S" & Last_Row).Value = strRemarks
        dstXlWb.Worksheets("Tasks").Range("Y" & Last_Row).Value = strTask
        dstXlWb.Worksheets("Tasks").Range("W" & Last_Row).Value = "=+TEXT(QATM[[#This Row],[End Date]]," & """MM""" & ")"
        dstXlWb.Worksheets("Tasks").Range("X" & Last_Row).Value = "=+TEXT(QATM[[#This Row],[End Date]]," & """YYYY""" & ")"


        If CheckBox1.CheckState = CheckState.Checked Then
            dstXlWb.Worksheets("Tasks").Range("R" & Last_Row).Value = "=""FOR QAT"" " & "& " & "TEXT(" & dstXlWb.Worksheets("Tasks").Range("E" & Last_Row).Value + 1 & ", ""00"")"
        Else
            dstXlWb.Worksheets("Tasks").Range("R" & Last_Row).Value = "YES"
        End If

        'Step 5 - Saving
        bgw.ReportProgress(Convert.ToInt32((5 / numToDo) * 100))
        'System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000)

        dstXlApp.ActiveWorkbook.Save()

    Catch ex As Exception

        'MsgBox(ex.Message)
        Me.Cursor = Cursors.Default
        MessageBox.Show("Please check excel file.")
        'MsgBox("Error has occured. " & ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly + MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Error")

        bgw.CancelAsync()
        Exit Sub

        srcXlWb.Close()
        dstXlWb.Close()
        srcXlApp.UserControl = True
        dstXlApp.UserControl = True
        srcXlApp.Quit()
        dstXlApp.Quit()

        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(dstXlWb)
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(dstXlWbs)
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(dstXlApp)
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(srcXlWb)
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(srcXlWbs)
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(srcXlApp)

        GC.Collect()
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers()
        GC.Collect()
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers()
        GC.Collect()
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers()
        GC.Collect()
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers()

    Finally

        'srcXlWb.Close()
        'dstXlWb.Close()
        'srcXlApp.UserControl = True
        'dstXlApp.UserControl = True
        'srcXlApp.Quit()
        'dstXlApp.Quit()

        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(dstXlWb)
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(dstXlWbs)
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(dstXlApp)
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(srcXlWb)
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(srcXlWbs)
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(srcXlApp)

        GC.Collect()
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers()
        GC.Collect()
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers()
        GC.Collect()
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers()
        GC.Collect()
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers()

    End Try




End Sub
```

Comment: Your code is too voluminous. I recommend you restructure it. There should be a `Main` procedure that controls the red thread, like create the application, open a workbook, close the workbook and quit the application. The Main should call a number of subs, each of which is dedicated to a particular task, like extracting data and making reports. Each of these subs may be assisted by functions which do calculations or manipulations and feed their results back to the subs. Your problem is contained in 10 lines of code max. With proper structure that's what you would give us to review.

Comment: can you help me with my codes. I did not study programming, I just built it by searching in google and with the help of my colleagues. That resulting I don't have much idea in programming. Its just that my system cannot add another data in the repository which I need to close the running app and then upload again to display it.

Comment: Have a look on here for some of the code questions which can give you an idea of structure - one of the benefits of Stack... See this for a simple example and look how the answers help: https://stackoverflow.com/q/40690592/4961700  Note I am not a programmer either but I found q&a on here that do show better practice.

Answer (score 0):

Private Declare Function GetWindowThreadProcessId Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal hwnd As IntPtr,
ByRef lpdwProcessId As Integer) As Integer

```
Friend Sub KillSpecificExcel(xlsApplication As Excel.Application)
    Try
        Dim psi As ProcessStartInfo = New ProcessStartInfo
        Dim XLProcID As Integer = 0
        Dim hwd As Integer

        hwd = xlsApplication.Hwnd
        GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwd, XLProcID)
        Dim XLProc As Process = Process.GetProcessById(XLProcID)
        psi.Arguments = $"/PID {XLProc.Id} /T /F"

        psi.FileName = "taskkill"
        Dim p As Process = New Process()
        p.StartInfo = psi
        p.Start()
    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw
    End Try
End Sub
```