# Excel VBA- How to loop through specific sheets in a workbook and format the same ranges in each sheet

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I have 10 sheets labeled 1-10 respectively and I want to loop through each sheet and format the same ranges in each sheet.

The below code works but I cannot get it to loop through each sheet

```
Sub Macro1()
'

Dim wsList() As String, wsName As Variant, ws As Worksheet
   
wsList = Split("1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10", " ")
    
For Each wsName In wsList
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(wsName)
      
    Range("A4:C7,L4:Q5,L6:L7,S24:U27,AD24:AF27,AO28:AR29,AO26:AO27").Select
    
        With Selection.Interior
            .Pattern = xlNone
            .TintAndShade = 0
            .PatternTintAndShade = 0
        End With
    
    Range("B4:C7,M4:Q5,T24:U27,AE24:AF27,AP28:AR29").Select
    Selection.Locked = False
    Selection.FormulaHidden = False
    
    Range("O31:AF34").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "FALL"
    Range("O35").Select
    
Next wsName

End Sub
```

Comment: Have a look at an example of a loop: https://stackoverflow.com/q/40690592/4961700

Comment: You have `Set ws=` but the Ranges are not qualified with a worksheet reference. Add `ws.` to the `Range(    )` statements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you write `Range(...)`, VBA will always use the `ActiveSheet`. What you want is that is works on worksheet `ws`, so you have to tell VBA it: `ws.Range(...)`.

Also, there is no need to use `Select` and `Selection` (and you should avoid it, it is almost never needed): Instead, either assign the Range to a variable and use that, or use a `With`-clause:

```
Dim wsList() As String, wsName As Variant, ws As Worksheet
   
wsList = Split("1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10", " ")

    For Each wsName In wsList
        Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(wsName)
          
        ' Option a) Use a Variable
        Dim myRange as Range
        Set myRange = ws.Range("A4:C7,L4:Q5,L6:L7,S24:U27,AD24:AF27,AO28:AR29,AO26:AO27")
        
        With myRange.Interior
            .Pattern = xlNone
            .TintAndShade = 0
            .PatternTintAndShade = 0
        End With
        ' Or, without With
        myRange.Interior.Pattern = xlNone
        myRange.Interior.TintAndShade = 0
        myRange.Interior.PatternTintAndShade = 0

        ' Option b) Use With directly with intermediate variable
        With ws.Range("B4:C7,M4:Q5,T24:U27,AE24:AF27,AP28:AR29")
            .Locked = False
            .FormulaHidden = False
        End With

        ws.Range("O31:AF34").FormulaR1C1 = "FALL"
    Next wsName
```

Your formula for the range "O31:AF34" looks odd, btw. This is not a valid formula. If you want to write the text `"FALL"` into the cell, use `ws.Range("O31:AF34").Value = "FALL"`

Comment: Thank you.  However, the debugger flagged ```.Pattern = xlNone``` (Run-time eror 438- Object doesn't support this property or method)

Comment: Also, ```ws.Range("O31:AF34").Value = "FALL"``` came from recording the macro

Comment: Sorry, error with cut&paste - corrected