# Report for individuals from master table in excel

Tags: excel, vba

There is a master report for student fees and individual report sheet needs to be created for student A on a separate sheet, all columns of master report are not to be included. In the individual reports, the data is transposed and only 4 columns are shown- Date, Class, Fee Tuition and Fee Exam.
Master report-

[image: Master Report]
And the individual report for Student A on a separate sheet-

[image: Student A sheet report]

This thing needs to be done by macro. Currently the macro is looping through all the rows and identifying the rows that belong to Student A but after that how best this can be done? Thanks for any help.

````
Set MasterSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Master")
Set TargetSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("StudentA")
LastRow = MasterSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To LastRow
    If MasterSheet.Range("B" & i).Value = "A" Then 'B column has names
        lastColumn = MasterSheet.Cells(1, MasterSheet.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        For j = 1 To lastColumn
        
        Next j
    End If
Next i```
````

Comment: Unnecessarily inefficient to loop through each row of the table. Sort the table by Name, then filter by each Name successively and copy visible rows only.

Comment: As suggested by @JosWoolley ... for example: `crit = "A"` then filter the table `With Sheet1.ListObjects("Table1").Range:` with "crit": `.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=crit`. then copy the visible cell `.SpecialCells(xlVisible).Copy`. paste transpose to sheet2 `Sheet2.Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
        False, Transpose:=True` .. remove the filter `.AutoFilter Field:=2` then close the with `end with`. Finally remove row 2 in sheet2 because it doesn need the name : `Sheet2.Rows(2).Delete`

Comment: Oops... the copy code should be like this : `.Resize(.Rows.Count, 5).SpecialCells(xlVisible).Copy` NOT `.SpecialCells(xlVisible).Copy` so it copy column A to E only.

Comment: Perhaps see this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/40690592/4961700