# Codes to extract data from group of excel files needed

Tags: python, excel, extract

I have a group of excel files, which contains hundreds of strings of text. Each of these string contains different names of people and the company they work for. What I'm trying to do is a code that allows me to have all the strings about a certain company from all the excel files.
I'm not a programmer, I barely know html so I'm very confused.

I've been suggested to use python and that's what I got:

```
import os
import pandas as pd

def extract_company_data(folder_path, company_name):
    # Get a list of all Excel files in the specified folder
    excel_files = [f for f in os.listdir(folder_path) if f.endswith('.xlsx')]

    # Create an empty DataFrame to store the extracted data
    extracted_data = pd.DataFrame()

    # Iterate over each Excel file
    for file in excel_files:
        file_path = os.path.join(folder_path, file)
        try:
            # Read the Excel file into a DataFrame
            df = pd.read_excel(file_path)
            # Filter the DataFrame for rows containing the company name
            filtered_data = df[df['Column_name'].str.contains(company_name, na=False)]
            # Append the filtered data to the extracted_data DataFrame
            extracted_data = extracted_data.append(filtered_data)
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error processing file {file}: {str(e)}")

    # Reset the index of the extracted_data DataFrame
    extracted_data.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)

    # Save the extracted data to a new Excel file
    extracted_data.to_excel('extracted_data.xlsx', index=False)

    print(f"Extraction completed. Extracted data saved to 'extracted_data.xlsx'.")

# Provide the folder path where the Excel files are located
folder_path = 'C:\Users\mcaponigri\Downloads\CF-ABILITATI'
# Provide the name of the company to extract data for
company_name = 'BANCA MEDIOLANUM SPA'

extract_company_data(folder_path, company_name)
```

Of course it's not working. Can you help me?

Comment: I did something like this in vba: https://stackoverflow.com/q/40690592/4961700

Comment: _"Of course it's not working"_: Please be more specific.

Comment: Please share the sample data format in excel. Also What is your desired output and the one you are getting after running above program ?

Answer (score -1):

did you see one of these messages:

```
Error processing file #### : ####
Extraction completed. Extracted data saved to 'extracted_data.xlsx'.
```

if you didn't see this messages or any messages, you must wait. maybe the files are very big and a lot.

if you opened the file and file closed, you must open it with python IDLE and press `f5` and wait to see one of that messages. next you can find your new file.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).