# How do you run 600 scenarios through a model in excel using VBA code?

Tags: excel, vba

Does any body have vba code to create 600 scenarios in excel? I have an excel model and need to run 600 scenarios through the model. It is a sort of sensitivity testing model, so the input variables that are used are the same in each scenario, but only the values of the input variables change from scenario to scenario.
I have these 600 scenarios' input data ready and the model is ready, but what vba code can I use to run the 600 scenarios through the model at the same time (without needing to use the model manually 600 times)?

I tried vba code I found online, but it doesn't seem to be working:

```
Sub CreateScenarioManager()

'Declare variables
Dim scenarioManager As ScenarioManager
Dim scenario As Scenario
Dim i As Integer

'Set the scenario manager
Set scenarioManager = ActiveWorkbook.ScenarioManager

'Loop through all of the input variables
For i = 1 To 600

'Create a new scenario
Set scenario = scenarioManager.Scenarios.Add(Name: "Scenario " & i)

'Specify the changing cells for the scenario
scenario.ChangingCells.Add Range("A1", "A2", "A6", "A9")

Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: You mean a vba looping macro something like: https://stackoverflow.com/q/40690592/4961700

Comment: and it's just curious - what can be a whole task when 600 of scenarios can be needed? Usually there are used from 2 to 10 scenarios for the table - for example, if table is counting price change with discount with step-10%. How can a user work with 600 scenarios?

Answer (score 1):

Think, you don't need scenario manager
To add a scenario it's just enough

```
ActiveSheet.Scenarios.Add

Sub CreateScenarioManager()

'Declare variables
'Dim scenarioManager1 As scenarioManager
Dim scenario As scenario
Dim i As Integer

'Set the scenario manager
'Set scenarioManager = ActiveWorkbook.scenarioManager

'Loop through all of the input variables
For i = 1 To 600

'Create a new scenario
ActiveSheet.Scenarios.Add Name:="Scenario " & i, ChangingCells:=Range("A1, A2, A6, A9") _
        , Values:=Array("7", "5", "5", "1"), Comment:= _
        "", Locked:=True, Hidden:=False

'Specify the changing cells for the scenario

Next i

End Sub
```

This way it works no problem For values you can create a 2-dimensional array, for example

```
Dim VLs(600,4)
```

and loop as so

```
   ActiveSheet.Scenarios.Add Name:="Scenario " & i, ChangingCells:=Range("A1, A2, A6, A9"), Values:=Array(VLs(i,1), VLs(i,2), VLs(i,3), VLs(i,4)), Comment:= _
            "something"&i, Locked:=True, Hidden:=False
```