# Export a Specific Worksheet to PDF (MAC)

Tags: excel, vba, macos

I want to make an Excel Macro that print a specific worksheet as PDF. On Sheet3 to there is a button that will start the Macro that will print Sheet3. This should work on a MAC computer.

This is the code I wrote for the Macro, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
Sub PrintToPDF()

Dim NoDepArr As String

NoDepArr = Range("C6").Value

Sheet3.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
  NoDepArr & " " & "Contract.pdf" _
  , Quality:=xlQualityMinimum, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas _
  :=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False
                                                       
End Sub
```

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Please explain specifically what doesn't work. Do you get an error?

Comment: What happens? *"Doesn't seem to work"* is not really helpful. Do you get any error message? Have you checked the content of Cell R6? Does it contain a valid path? Maybe you simply forgot to add the Path-Separator (I think it's a slash on Mac) between `NoDepArr` and the filename? Do you have permission to write to the folder? Can you execute the command manually from Excel?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [mac excel vba loop : from list & then export as pdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40690592/mac-excel-vba-loop-from-list-then-export-as-pdf)

Answer (score 0):

in the end I found the answer of my problem. The sheet was hidden and in that way it could not be used in this expression. When the sheet is isn't hidden the macro works. Is there a solution to print a hidden sheet?

Comment: *Is there a solution to print a hidden sheet?* Please ask another separate question.

Comment: Welcome Steven! Read [The Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and earn your first badge! According to your badges, you haven't taken the tour, and thus likely also not looked at How to Ask, What topics can I ask about here? and related help pages. Please do so now! Stack Overflow has some specific rules, e.g. on the scope (must be detailed and focused on one issue) and style of question (e.g. must be self-contained), that you should familiarise yourself with to ask well-received question.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like your `Sheet3.ExportAsFixedFormat` should be `Sheets("Sheet3").ExportAsFixedFormat` like below:

```vb
    Sub PrintToPDF()
    
    Dim NoDepArr As String
    
    NoDepArr = Range("C6").Value
    
    Sheets("Sheet3").ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
      NoDepArr & " " & "Contract.pdf" _
      , Quality:=xlQualityMinimum, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas _
      :=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False
                                                           
    End Sub
```

Comment: Assuming that `Sheet3` is the codename of the sheet in question, it's perfectly valid.